# How can we represent a summary of clusters in density-based algorithms (DBSCAN)?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I would like to ask you a question: How can we represent a cluster in density-based algorithms? In other words, in prototype-based algorithms the clusters represent by centroids and number of data points, in model-based represent by centroids and variance, in grid-based represent by length, height, and a number of data points in each grid. So, what about the density-based algorithms(DBSCAN), how would we represent the summary of output clusters?

Answer (score 0):

The clusters of DBSCAN are best described by the set of core points.

Clearly, there cannot be a "fixed size" summary, because the clusters can have arbitrary complex shapes.

It's not just DBSCAN. What about **hierarchical clustering**?
It's the *eyception* that you have a compact "summary model" of the cluster; the more common situation is that **a clusters is simply a set of points**.